# translate gaussian noise in opencv to emgu cv

Tags: c#, opencv, noise, emgucv

I'm studying Image Processing and i need to make gaussian noise in c# with emgu cv.
i find the code

> Mat gaussian_noise = img.clone();
>
> randn(gaussian_noise,128,30);

is make gaussian noise in open cv.
what is the traslate code in emgu cv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit, I found out that the [equivalent to randn on Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/af09d20f-6e72-ed1a-bcfc-3cee082865a8.htm) is the SetRandNormal(MCvScalar, MCvScalar) method on Matrix. So, to make something similar to your code, you'll have to do:

```
//Create your image as Image<Bgr,byte> here, for example.
Matrix<byte> matrix = new Matrix<byte>(img.Width, img.Height);
CvInvoke.cvConvert(img, matrix);
matrix.SetRandNormal(new MCvScalar(128), new MCvScalar(30));
//And Here you can convert back to image and do whatever you want.
```

That should work, but I don't have Emgu installed on this machine, so I can't test it right now.

Good luck!